# Adding dynamic entries in c++ map

Tags: c++, stl

I know this may be a silly question but I'm new to c++ and I could not find answer to my question.

I'm using STL std::map to maintain a list of subscriptions and their remote server IPs and PORTs. The number of servers may vary from subscription to subscription. If the number of server is 2 for a subscription then there would be 2 IP addresses and 2 ports entries for that subscription. If 1 server then 1 IP and 1 PORT.

```
std::map<std::string, SubscriptionInfo> sub_list;

struct ServerInfo {
    u_int32_t        ip;
    u_int16_t        port;
};

struct SubscriptionInfo {
    u_int64_t        subscriptionId;
    int              no_of_servers;
    ServerInfo       *remote;
};
```

I have the subscription related info in form of c struct from where I can copy the the data to map entry. However, I'm not sure how can I add and delete an entry to/from map by considering the above. Is it possible with map at all or are there other alternatives?

Comment: Drop the `ServerInfo *` and use a `std::vector<ServerInfo>`. Then the `no_of_servers` also goes away.since the vector knows its own size.

Comment: Use `std::vector<ServerInfo>` inside your `SubscriptionInfo`.  Always prefer not to use pointers unless no other alternative can be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As my comment suggested, you should strive to not use pointers where they're not necessary, such as `ServerInfo *remote;` and simply use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

struct ServerInfo {
    uint32_t        ip;
    uint16_t        port;
    ServerInfo(uint32_t io_ = 0, uint16_t port_= 0) : 
               ip(ip_), port(_port) {}
};

struct SubscriptionInfo {
    uint64_t        subscriptionId;
    std::vector<ServerInfo> remote;
    SubscriptionInfo(uint64_t val = 0) : subscriptionId(val) {}
};
```

I updated the `SubscriptionInfo` to add a constructor that takes the `subscriptionId`.

Once you have this, adding an existing key and subscription info can be done using  [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, SubscriptionInfo> sub_list;

    // insert an item into the map.  If already existing, return
    // the iterator to the existing item
    auto iter = sub_list.insert({"1",                  // string
                                SubscriptionInfo(1)}). // subscription info
                                first; // item that was inserted, or
                                       // existing item if already in map.

    // push back a new ip and port into the vector.
    (*iter).second.remote.push_back({ 100,18 });  // add IP and port 18
}
```

So basically we used `std::map::insert` to insert a new item into the map.  The return value of `std::map::insert` returns a `std::pair`, where the `first` of this pair is the iterator to the item that was inserted, or if already existed in the map, an iterator to the already existing map entry.

That's why we don't have to check if the item exists or not -- all we need to do is call `push_back` on the `remote` member since we're going to get back an iterator to the new or existing entry on `insert` (note that the map itself stores its entries as `std::pair<key_type, value_type>`, so we want the `second` of this pair to get the `SubscriptionInfo` instance).

Also note that we do not need a separate member variable to keep track of the number of servers, as `remote.size()` returns the number of entries in the vector.  Having extraneous variables such as `no_of_servers` increases the chance that bugs occur due to not manually updating this variable whenever items are added or removed from the vector.  Instead, always use `std::vector::size()` to get you the correct amount.

To delete an entry, all you need is the `key` value, and the entry is deleted by calling the `std::map::erase()` function:

```
    sub_list.erase("1"); // removes key "1" and the data associated with it
```

Edit:  If you're using a compiler that is not C++ 11 compliant, the following changes should be made to the call to `insert`:

```
    typedef std::map<std::string, SubscriptionInfo> MapStringToSub;
    //...
    // insert an item into the map.  If already existing, return
    // the iterator to the existing item
    MapStringToSub::iterator iter = sub_list.insert(std::make_pair("1",  // string
                                SubscriptionInfo(1))). // subscription info
                                first; // item that was inserted, or
                                       // existing item if already in map.

    // push back a new ip and port into the vector.
    (*iter).second.remote.push_back(ServerInfo(100,18));  // add IP and port 18
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Now, I understand how can I achieve that using map and vector.

Comment: Now, I'm using it as follows:

`for (i = 0; i < sub_data->no_of_svrs; i++) {
                (*itr).second.remote.push_back({ sub_data->remote[i].r_ip, sub_data->remote[i].r_port });  
        }`

But getting following error while compiling:
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

Comment: Are you using a standard  C++11 compiler?  The syntax uses the brace initializer, and that doesn't exist on 03 or 1998 compilers.

Comment: we use Gcc 4.2 for our development purpose. Is there any other syntax that I can use? or workaround.

Comment: @C_user5 See my edited code.  I created a constructor for `ServerInfo` that takes an ip and port.  However, you should get away from using 4.2 and use, at the very least, a C++ 11 compliant compiler.

Comment: we are on the same page now! ;-) because meanwhile I also tried the same solution (creating a constructor for `ServerInfo` and then calling that with args in `push_back()`. I wanted to show you that peice of code for correctness but guess what you suggested the same! Thanks a lot!!